# Variant Selection on Product Page

Tags: e-commerce

Is there a better way to show variants of products with better call outs like, if that combination is out of stock try other combination or get 50% off on other variation.

Also, should we place the variants near the product gallery or after the product name and price?

Attaching a screenshot for reference[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think Amazon has some intersting examples here.
They are using the photo with different colour for each product colour.
If one product is not in that colour they simply grey out the product type when the colour is selected.

I think you can present a discount message when the user has selected a colour + type are not available. Maybe show them a discount code voucher they can use on checkout.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that illusion where collored text appears as for example: the word blue is collored red, the word black is collored yellow and it messes up your brains ?

Starting from this I would create the color options with also showing the color itself.
Aside from that the colors and options should sit under title and price.
To portray that some options might have a discount you can either show the price interval : 1200 - 1800 $.

Comment: Can you give me an exmaple @christian ?

Comment: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/2042369676.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.570c44d33ogTR4&algo_pvid=2a62a72e-2f0f-47c9-8238-beb8dd89f505&algo_expid=2a62a72e-2f0f-47c9-8238-beb8dd89f505-0&btsid=0bb0624516070621620288186efec9&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_